# Crontab runs but nothing happens

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

**I want to simulate a wallpapers slideshow** (pictures are fetched from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/)) almost the same as on Windows 7 but on Ubuntu. So for this purpose I decide to use [unsplash-wallpaper](https://github.com/cuth/unsplash-wallpaper/).

I created a bash script `.refresh-wallpaper.sh` and placed it to home direcotry:

```
#!/bin/bash
unsplash-wallpaper -r --dir "~/Pictures/wallpapers"
```

Then I install a crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * * sh ~/.refresh-wallpaper.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**The script runs by crond but nothing happened**:

```
Dec 17 22:12:01 pcname CRON[11933]: (username) CMD (sh ~/.refresh-wallpaper.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

..but it works when it launched manually via terminal:

```
username@pcname:~$ sh .refresh-wallpaper.sh 
Request https://source.unsplash.com/random
Downloading [==================================================================]
✔︎ Image saved to /home/username/Pictures/wallpapers/wallpaper-photo-1511620356826-e2ed21a61991.jpg
Check it out.
```

**What I do wrong?** Thanks for any interaction!

**EDIT1**: It works because new images are saved and output redirects to the log but wallpapers doesn't check out on desktop.

Comment: Just look at the output by calling `bash -x ~/..sh > /tmp/log` instead of silencing the whole thing.

Comment: Btw.: `sh` is not `bash`.

Comment: @Pavel, thanks for reply. it works because new images are saved and output redirects to the log but wallpapers doesn't check out. have you any ideas to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the quotation marks in your script prevent the expansion of `~` in this line:

```
unsplash-wallpaper -r --dir "~/Pictures/wallpapers"
```

I suggest to use:

```
unsplash-wallpaper -r --dir "$HOME/Pictures/wallpapers"
```

Comment: But why does it work when run manually? The script has the quoting problem also then.